# Cross domain requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xss

I have a script file loaded from `mydomain.com` that makes ajax requests to that domain. The script though is loaded on some other domain which initializes it and then tells it when to make the requests. I'm running into issues though because the browser is thinks it's a cross domain request. I thought that whatever domain the script file was loaded from was able to make requests back to that origin? Here's some code as an example:

Page at `someotherdomain.com`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/test.js"></script>
        <title>Cross-Domain Ajax Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p id="ajax-response"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          Test.testAjax();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script loaded from `mydomain.com`

```
Test = { 
    testAjax: function() {
        //make ajax request to http://mydomain.com/myendpoint
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that whatever domain the script file was loaded from was able to make requests back to that origin?

No. The origin is *always* the *page* not the script.

Comment: so how do things like google analytics or other javascript api libraries make their calls?

Comment: Either they make write only requests, or they use JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your script is violating the cross-domain restriction by by being served from one domain, but requesting a script on another domain.

> What's the right approach?

There are two possibilites:

1. Place both the running script and the called script under the same domain.
2. Use `dataType = "jsonp"` to bypass the restriction. jQuery will perform some magic (replacing the call with an inline script reference in the format of `<script src="mydomain.com/endpoint" />` to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the script will always be `mydomain.com`! You could either make use of an Ajax Proxy (through your backend) or eventually **[JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)** is your way to go (more likely both, depends on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

When you load the javascript it is as if the code is on `someotherdomain.com` and you will have cross-domain issues going from that domain to `mydomain.com`.